# Angular Input property, it seems I cannot reassign it multiple times

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7. And I am having an unexpected behavior.

parent component code:

```
 parcial_result:boolean = false;

 fetchData(): void {
   this.parcial_result = true;
 }


....
<app-window [visible]="parcial_result"></app-window>
```

After I fetch some data from the server I show a component, by setting parcial_result property to true.

My child component

```
@Input() visible: boolean = true;

constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    //if the user clicks outside this component I hide it again.

  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {

    } else {
     this.visible = false; //as soon this code executes I cannnot set visible to true by using the parent component

   //setting parcial_result to true on the parent doesn't affect the visible variable anymore.  

    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
```

It seems I cannot reassign the input property . How can I remedy this.

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproduction using https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the parent component's `parcial_result` already is set to `true` so you cannot reassign it to `true` to see changes. In order to make this work, you need to communicate the change to the parent component. Use an output for that. I'll provide an example in a jiffy.

Parent component

```
parcial_result:boolean = false;

fetchData(): void {
  this.parcial_result = true;
}
....
<app-window [visible]="parcial_result"
            (hide)="parcial_result = false"></app-window>
```

Your child component

```
@Input() visible: boolean = true;
@Output() hide = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    //if the user clicks outside this component I hide it again.

  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {

    } else {
      // instead of setting the prop, we just inform the parent
      hide.emit();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child component should emit changes to "visible." For this, you can [create a two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---).

Child component:

```
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() visible: boolean = false;
    @Output() visibleChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    fetchData(): void {
       this.visible= true;
       this.visibleChange.emit(this.parcial_result);
    }
}
```

Parent Template:

```
<app-window [(visible)]="parcial_result"></app-window>
```